# How to Flash Patched_Boot.img via termux?

Tags: fastboot, termux

Is there a way to get termux to process Fastboot cmds or flash a patched_boot.img with out a PC?

Comment: fastboot cmd is usually Fastboot flash boot --slot=all magisk_patched-24314_GyPru.img so what would i type in termux

Comment: you realize fastboot is reading file from PC though? type in termux *'su; ls -d /dev/block/\*/\*/\*/by-name/boot\*'*

Comment: https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/4356231

Answer (score 0):

no, there is no way to unlock bootloader nor root your device from termux (except for nexus devices). you can however run fastboot commands from another rooted device with [Magisk module](https://github.com/Magisk-Modules-Repo/adb-ndk), or flash partitions with `dd` if termux is running on already rooted device

```
$ su
# ls -d /dev/block/*/*/*/by-name/boot*
# dd if=/storage/0815-4711/patched_boot.img of=/dev/block/platform/11120000.ufs/by-name/boot_a
# dd if=/storage/0815-4711/patched_boot.img of=/dev/block/platform/11120000.ufs/by-name/boot_b
```

Comment: Bootloader is Unlocked, PC crashed and must flashed patched boot.img